# Crash: nma_deice_log_size_bytes

Tags: here-api, here-ios, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm receiving this crash from Firebase Crashlytics with only versions iOS 13.5.1 and 14 (beta). The strange is that with previous versions this problem does not occur.

I have installed the SDK HEREMaps 3.13.3. I can't find how to resolve it. Any idea what happend?

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001a05206b8

```
0   libdispatch.dylib              0x1a05206b8 <redacted> + 28
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04ee82c <redacted> + 194
2   NMAKit                         0x103bc7178 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 355904
3   NMAKit                         0x103c0c63c nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 639748
4   NMAKit                         0x103c0c204 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 638668
5   UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb5e48 <redacted> + 2096
6   UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
7   UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
8   UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
9   UIKitCore                      0x1a547a16c <redacted> + 988
10  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
11  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
12  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1e2868164 <redacted> + 556
13  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
14  UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
15  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
16  UIKitCore                      0x1a53cd040 <redacted> + 192
17  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
18  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
19  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1e2868024 <redacted> + 236
20  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
21  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
22  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bba200 <redacted> + 176
23  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
24  UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
25  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
26  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb502c <redacted> + 492
27  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb7a48 <redacted> + 1072
28  UIKitCore                      0x1a489e0a4 <redacted> + 592
29  UIKitCore                      0x1a489e450 <redacted> + 196
30  UIKitCore                      0x1a489eb08 <redacted> + 32
31  UIKitCore                      0x1a47d9718 <redacted> + 104
32  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3e738 <redacted> + 344
33  UIKitCore                      0x1a49f56d0 <redacted> + 104
34  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3e9a4 <redacted> + 436
35  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3e390 <redacted> + 448
36  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3d634 <redacted> + 432
37  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3d3c4 <redacted> + 688
38  UIKitCore                      0x1a4a3cab0 <redacted> + 40
39  UIKitCore                      0x1a5448784 <redacted> + 72
40  UIKitCore                      0x1a4f96f94 <redacted> + 300
41  UIKitCore                      0x1a4f85e60 <redacted> + 204
42  UIKitCore                      0x1a4fb9210 <redacted> + 80
43  CoreFoundation                 0x1a07ce30c <redacted> + 36
44  CoreFoundation                 0x1a07c8aa4 <redacted> + 520
45  CoreFoundation                 0x1a07c87c8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 628
46  Foundation                     0x1a0b63fa0 <redacted> + 232
47  NMAKit                         0x103eecd40 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1801892
48  NMAKit                         0x103efeddc mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1875776
49  NMAKit                         0x103f0db48 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1936556
50  NMAKit                         0x103f0d070 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1933780
51  NMAKit                         0x103f0a000 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1921380
52  NMAKit                         0x103ef63fc mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1840480
53  NMAKit                         0x103ef06dc mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1816640
54  NMAKit                         0x103ef02d0 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1815604
55  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04edf08 <redacted> + 20
56  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04ef68c <redacted> + 32
57  NMAKit                         0x103ef0298 mpa::ApplicationContext::_here_sdk_version_3_13_3_105_(void*) + 1815548
58  NMAKit                         0x103b03be8 (Falta)
59  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04edf08 <redacted> + 20
60  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04ef68c <redacted> + 32
61  NMAKit                         0x103b03a74 (Falta)
62  NMAKit                         0x103b07c08 (Falta)
63  NMAKit                         0x103b07aa0 (Falta)
64  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04edf08 <redacted> + 20
65  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04ef68c <redacted> + 32
66  NMAKit                         0x103b07a60 (Falta)
67  NMAKit                         0x103bc7d14 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 358876
68  NMAKit                         0x103bc71b0 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 355960
69  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04edf08 <redacted> + 20
70  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a04ef68c <redacted> + 32
71  NMAKit                         0x103bc7178 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 355904
72  NMAKit                         0x103c0c63c nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 639748
73  NMAKit                         0x103c0c204 nma_deice_log_size_bytes + 638668
74  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb5e48 <redacted> + 2096
75  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
76  UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
77  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
78  UIKitCore                      0x1a547a16c <redacted> + 988
79  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
80  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
81  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1e2868164 <redacted> + 556
82  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
83  UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
84  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
85  UIKitCore                      0x1a53cd040 <redacted> + 192
86  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
87  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
88  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1e2868024 <redacted> + 236
89  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
90  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
91  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bba200 <redacted> + 176
92  UIFoundation                   0x1a439de84 <redacted> + 700
93  UIFoundation                   0x1a439e09c <redacted> + 1236
94  UIFoundation                   0x1a432b0a0 <redacted> + 312
95  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb502c <redacted> + 492
96  UIKitCore                      0x1a4bb7a48 <redacted> + 1072
97  UIKitCore                      0x1a489e0a4 <redacted> + 592
98  UIKitCore                      0x1a489e450 <redacted> + 196
99  UIKitCore                      0x1a489eb08 <redacted> + 32
100 UIKitCore                      0x1a47e4d7c <redacted> + 368
101 UIKitCore                      0x1a47e5b58 <redacted> + 880
102 UIKitCore                      0x1a47e6ed8 <redacted> + 168
103 UIKitCore                      0x1a47c9390 <redacted> + 228
104 UIKit                          0x1dd7f0794 <redacted> + 52
105 UIKitCore                      0x1a54aa7d8 <redacted> + 2204
106 QuartzCore                     0x1a8478a48 <redacted> + 296
107 QuartzCore                     0x1a8478f04 <redacted> + 524
108 QuartzCore                     0x1a848d2bc <redacted> + 144
109 QuartzCore                     0x1a83d62e8 <redacted> + 416
110 QuartzCore                     0x1a84015ac <redacted> + 732
111 UIKitCore                      0x1a4fa5bfc <redacted> + 84
112 CoreFoundation                 0x1a07cf010 <redacted> + 28
113 CoreFoundation                 0x1a07ce618 <redacted> + 356
114 CoreFoundation                 0x1a07c8eec <redacted> + 852
115 CoreFoundation                 0x1a07c8788 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 564
116 GraphicsServices               0x1ac6a3820 GSEventRunModal + 164
117 UIKitCore                      0x1a4f871d8 <redacted> + 1072
118 UIKitCore                      0x1a4f8d0b8 UIApplicationMain + 1876
119 Chofer PRO                     0x1029ae06c main + 40 (AppDelegate.swift:40)
120 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a06543d4 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole .crash file with metadata, so I can symbolicate the crash. Or please share the steps to reproduce.
Also, I would recommend to upgrade to the latest HERE SDK version 3.16.3.